# How can I stop vs code terminal from opening everytime I save a change

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started using git. and I notice that every time I save a change in my Vs Code editor with "Ctrl s," the terminal will automatically open. how can I stop this.

I have gone to the settings in Vs Code to find any option that can address this. but I couldn't

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot showing what the terminal looks like after it automatically opens? You can add the screenshot by editing your question.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.